# Can a simulacrum use magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement, simulacrum

Can a simulacrum use magic items such as wands?  Would it matter if the item requires Attunement?

Answer (score 17):

## Yes, it can use items

The only differences between the *simulacrum* (*Player's Handbook 5th ed, p276*) and the target creature are that it has half as many hit points as the original, it is formed *without* equipment, and that the simulacrum cannot gain abilities, advance, or regain expended spell slots.

> The duplicate is a creature...and it can and take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature...
> ...Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the duplicated creature.

It can use items provided to it, and attune with them as normal.

@keithcurtis noted that since items can only be attuned to one creature at a time (*Dungeon Master's Guide 5th ed., p 138*), the *simulacrum* is not attuned to the items that the target was at the time of the *simulacrum's* creation, and must attune as normal during short rests.